# Wordpress doesn't apply rotation to iPhone images

Tags: iphone, ios, wordpress

When I upload iPhone images to my Wordpress site the images taken with an iPhone rotates wrong. On my computer the rotation is correct but when uploading it the rotation gets wrong.

Any ideas?

*Update:* The Wordpress UI rotation tool isn't an option because it relies on me inserting the image to a post, which I'm not doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many cameras store the orientation (portrait or landscape) in the [EXIF metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) of the image file. The actual pixel data is not rotated, but the metadata contains the information necessary for the viewing program to display it correctly.

Wordpress seems to apply the rotation to resized versions, [but ignore it for the full size images](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14459). There is a plugin that takes care of this problem: [Image Rotation Repair](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-rotation-repair/) (I haven't used this myself, though).

Note: This will only apply to images that are uploaded to and processed by Wordpress, not to images linked from a different location via URL.

Comment: I would recommend using [Image Rotation Fixer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/image-rotation-fixer/). It is a bit newer and implemented as a hook so it can be used together with other plugins that implement a similar hook.

Answer (score 0):

When uploading an image to wordpress you can click "Edit Image" and easily rotate it to the correct orientation.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue because I'm using custom fields where I paste the url link to the image. The Wordpress UI orientation only applies if you insert the image to a post.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your images to PNG using another program and then upload to Wordpress it should fix the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this WordPress plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ios-images-fixer/

It automatically fixes iOS images' orientation.